# How echo json data in a Magento controller on a valid way?

Tags: php, plugin, json

I have created a Magento plugin. In this plugin I call (with ajax) a custom controller where I echo some `json` data:

```
public function testAction()
{
   echo json_encode('test');
   exit;
}
```

But when I try to upload my plugin to the Magento Marketplace, I get 2 errors:

- Use of exit language construct is discouraged.
- Use of echo language construct is discouraged.

How can I output `json` data in a controller on a valid way?

Comment: magento 1 or 2? It looks like 1 but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

End your action with this.

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody(
    Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(your data here)
);
return;
```

Comment: I have facing same issue in Magento 2 How to resolve it...

Comment: @phpdeveloper Exactly how I wrote in the answer.